# Halakhic problem with indirectly effecting posthumous Mormon baptism?

Tags: halacha, death, christianity, family-members

Would there be any halakhic problem with using LDS resources to do family history research, if you knew it would result in deceased Jews being named in posthumous baptism rituals?  Or is this completely irrelevant?

(Note that in practice this would not seem to be an issue, as they seem to have policies against posthumously baptizing people that have no connection to church members.  In any case, one can certainly look at LDS microfilms without providing the LDS church with any information about the people one is looking for.)

Comment: I always thought posthumous baptisms were irrelevant, since it's impossible to convert away from Judaism, and a dead body can't sin anymore.

Answer (score 4):

In general, ask your LOR. In theory, however, a person cannot "convert" someone else. An act of conversion is really an act of long-term idolatry. To say one can "convert" someone dead is like saying one can force a dead person to violate Shabbat. Clearly an impossible position.