# Do blessings and curses affect the dead?

Tags: blessing, curse, heaven

Do blessings and curses have any effect on the dead?

We say things like, " may his memory be a blessing," "may the Neshamah have an 'Aliyah," etc.

What effect does it have?

Comment: Related: [Can the living negatively affect the dead?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14346/can-the-living-negatively-affect-the-dead)

Answer (score 1):

Blessings have an effect. For example Kaddish takes the Neshama out of Gehenam and it raises Neshamot in Gan Eden to higher places (Shaar HaGilgulim Hk. 14).

HaRav Musafi writes in his Sefer (Shivat Sion) that when someone says Hashkava for someone after the first year of their death it can Has WeShalom have a negative effect and may Has Weshalom lead to the Neshama to get tortured. He also says that when someone reads the Haftara "Lezecher Nishmat" someone and makes mistakes it can also negatively effect the Neshama Has Weshalom.

So the answer is, **yes** our words and actions have effect up there.

Comment: Gavriel Would you not say that Kaddish and performing a mitzva "Lezecher Nishmat" are different to just saying "may his memory be a blessing" or "may the Neshamah have an 'Aliyah"?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I just don't see the difference.

Comment: Saying Kaddish causes HKB"H's great name to be praised. Doing a mitzva so to speak gives nachat to HKB"H. Uttering the other phrases seems to me not as powerful.